# .NET Core SQL Server Session State

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, session-state

I need to use SQL Server session state with my website and use it with the existing ASPState database that the customer has, this was a requirement.

However I noticed the table structure for doing session state in .NET Core differs from how the structure used to be. Does anyone know how to implement this or a work around?

**.NET Core Session State DB**
[image: .NET Core Session State DB]

**Previous Session State Versions**
[image: Previous Session State Versions]

Answer (score 1):

What you're wanting is not possible. Not only is the database table different, ASP.NET Core uses `DataProtectionProvider` for encryption, whereas ASP.NET utilizes the machine key. In other words, even if the schema *was* the same, one site wouldn't be able to decrypt the session state from the other.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've been googling all day! Is there a work around or another way I could do this? I really need to read the session data that the other sites are using

Comment: No. There's no workaround. However, this does serve as a good reminder to avoid use of sessions as much as possible. There's honestly not much you should really be storing in the session, if you're designing a web app properly. There are ways to share authentication, so setting claims on registered users would be far more preferable.